# Google Chrome extension that removes fonts in a website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, fonts

I'm new to Google Chrome extensions programming and JavaScript so please don't be hard on me. I'm trying to create an extension that changes in all posts fonts in a forum to a default font. I created a manifest file and managed to get the "posts" element :

```
var element = document.getElementById("posts");
```

now this element has classes inside of many different posts with their own unique id and each post has this class:

```
class="message"
```

there you can find the post with the font

```
<span style="font-family: comic sans ms"><u><i><b>...blabla</b></i></u></span>
```

and change it. Question is, from the element I got in the post, how can i change the value of the font?
edit:
here are the elements of the forum message
[image]

Comment: You could always look at the source code of a plugin that already does this:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en

Comment: @Brad I have interest of learning developing extensions, so I prefer to do it by myself. edit: oh, you told me to look at the source code, I thought you told me to use this extension. sorry

Comment: @Brad but where is the source code? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Google how to look at an extension code instead of asking here. Theres even an extension for it

Comment: You can also go to the documentation at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions.  Look at content scripts, but you might be able to just use the css attribute.

Comment: Eh I  managed to get the source code but there are so many scripts and the code is so long.. I'm pretty sure the answer to my question shouldn't be so long.. is there none that knows how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although a JS solution exists, CSS seems like a much better choice. For instance, to force all fonts matching the description in your question to be overridden (e.g. with the default monospace font), use the following stylesheet (contentstyle.css):

```css
#posts .message [style*="font-family:"] {
    font-family: monospace !important;
}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Replace font",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://example.com/*"],
        "css": ["contentstyle.css"],
        "all_frames": true
    }]
}
```

If you prefer to use JavaScript, and the page does not dynamically insert the tags, you could use the following [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

```js
var elems;
elems = document.querySelectorAll('#posts .message [style*="font-family:"]');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
    elems[i].style.fontFamily = 'monospace';
}
```

To learn how to construct these selectors, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors.

Although not tried, you could probably declare and insert a [`@font-face` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) to change how the `comic sans ms` font is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work. I'll edit in my post all the elements of the forum so maybe you will see why

Comment: @SpoocyCrep Your screenshot doesn't show any message class. The ID attributes do contain ".message" though. You can either use an attribute selector to match that attribute, or just remove the `.message` part of the selector since it doesn't appear to be important in your case.

Comment: I apologize for saying there is message class, I accidently looked at quote element. I tried removing the .message but it still doesn't work elems = document.querySelectorAll('#posts [style=*="font-family:"]');

Comment: @SpoocyCrep My bad, I  made a typo. The `=*=` should be `*=` (see my edited answer, and also take a look at the external references to learn more about CSS selectors).

Comment: Still wont do anything :(

Comment: @SpoocyCrep `#posts [style*="font-family:"]` ought to work given your screenshot. Did you reload the extension AND the page after changing your extension?